# F350 idling off and sputtering and small jerks as I drive

Tags: ford, idle, f-350

Haven't had the truck long it's a 1996 Ford f350 with7.5 liter engine it just filled gas tank so full or empty runs the same it is jerking small little jerks as I drive and it has no idle gage so I can't tell if that is messed up but it feels like it and it doesn't get any better if I take the gas cap off to see if it's a breather problem anyone know what's wrong or have suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: And I put heat and fuel injector cleaner in it to no better still sputtering.

Comment: It’s misfiring? Is the malfunction indicator lamp on?